# Making complex matrix real with unitary transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Consider the Hermitian matrices:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -0.7011-0.0912i & 0 \\
    -0.7011+0.0912i & 0 & 0.6702-0.2255i\\
    0 & 0.6702+0.2255i & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\ 
  B=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -0.0912+0.7011i & 0 \\
    -0.0912-0.7011i & 0 & -0.2255-0.6702i\\
    0 & -0.2255+0.6702i & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\\ $$

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to find a *diagonal* unitary matrix, $U$, that transforms $A$ and $B$ (individually) so that one matrix is purely real and the other purely imaginary? To be clear, I need $U$ to transform:
$$A'=UAU^{\dagger}\\B'=UBU^{\dagger}$$
so that one of $A'$ and $B'$ is purely real and the other purely imaginary (this transformation may not be possible, but that is what I would like to find out).

Comment: What does it mean for a diagonal matrix $D$ to "transform" $A$ to a purely real matrix? Does that mean that $DA$ is real? That $DAD^{-1}$ is real? Also, it's not clear what you mean by "individually". Are you looking for one matrix that does both of these things, or are you looking for (potentially) two different diagonal matrices?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I edited the question.

Comment: Can I ask why are you interested in this kinda matrix U? Also why those numbers?

Comment: I find that a helpful way to think of these diagonal similarities is to note that 
$$
\operatorname{diag}(u) A \operatorname{diag}(u)^\dagger = A \circ (uu^\dagger),
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard (entrywise) product.

Comment: @JKalle Regarding my deleted answer, the trick I had in mind works when the non-zero entries are on successive diagonals, but not in this case

Comment: @BenGrossmann, in any case, thank you for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that a helpful way to think of these diagonal similarities is to note that
$$
\operatorname{diag}(u) A \operatorname{diag}(u)^\dagger = A \circ (uu^\dagger), \tag{1}
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard (entrywise) product.

With (1), we can see that because for all entries of $B$ we have either $B_{jk} \in \{\pm i A_{jk}\}$, it follows that $[UBU^\dagger]_{ij} \in \{\pm i UAU^\dagger\}_{ij}$. So, it suffices to find $U = \operatorname{diag}(u)$ such that $UAU^\dagger$ has real entries.

Using (1), we have can see that we want $u$ such that
$$
a_{12} u_1 u_2^* \in \Bbb R, \quad a_{23} u_2 u_{3}^* \in \Bbb R,
$$
where $z^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$. One way to ensure this is to make it so that
$$
u_1^*u_2 = \frac{a_{12}}{|a_{12}|}, \quad u_2^* u_3 = \frac{a_{23}}{|a_{23}|}.
$$
Setting $u_1 = 1$ and applying these equations yields
$$
u_2 = \frac{a_{12}}{|a_{12}|}, \qquad u_3 = \frac{a_{12}a_{23}}{|a_{12}a_{23}|}.
$$

Comment: Note that $b_{21}=-i*a_{21}$, but $b_{12}\ne -i*a_{12}$

Comment: @JKalle Of course, that was a silly mistake. In any case, I believe that this transformation should work.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but by making the unitary transformation with this matrix, I find that the upper left block of each transformed matrix is either purely real or purely imaginary (as is what I want) but the entries $a_{23}$, $a_{32}$ and  $b_{23}$, $b_{32}$ each have both real and imaginary components.

Comment: @JKalle I guess I made a mistake then... Did you mean to say "upper right" rather than "upper left"?

Comment: No, the entries $a'_{12}$ and $a'_{21}$ are real, while $b'_{12}$ and $b'_{21}$ are imaginary.

Comment: @JKalle Interesting... I'll see if I can fix my answer

Comment: @JKalle It looks like I managed to fix it after all. It seems that I divided when I should have multiplied

Comment: @JKalle Not quite, see my edited answer.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you very much!